# Append elements to text box in new line using HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Suppose i have textbox :-

```
<input type="text" name="content"  id="content"/>
```

And i am trying append text to this input box in the following manner:-

```
document.getElementById("content").value+= "A";
```

The output is something like:-

```
AAAA....
```

Each time, the text is getting appended in the same line, how can make the text to append each time to the new line? Like that of below.

```
A
A
A
.
.
```

Comment: You may want to use a text area instead.  In an input type text, there is no next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an input type text, you can use a text area and then style it to look like a text box.

```
<textarea name="textarea_content" id="tx_content"></textarea>

document.getElementById("tx_content").value+= "A\n";
document.getElementById("tx_content").value+= "A\n";
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sx7t3ykc/

Answer (score 0):

The input textbox will support one single line. not multiple lines. that is it's behaviour. That's why your text is shown in a single line.

If you need multiple lines, then you need to use `<textarea></textarea>` element

Answer (score 0):

`input` is used for a single line. Try using `textarea`.

Refer code below:

```
<textarea type="text" name="content"  id="content">
</textarea>
```

and js will be like this:

```
document.getElementById("content").value+= "A\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made you an example that appends a new "A" char every 5 seconds. I use **textarea** instead of the **input** tag.

```js
setInterval(appendNewChar, 5000)

function appendNewChar()
{
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").value += "A\n";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @GuyFromChennai said, you have to use  tag instead of , also, writing '\n' will make the line break, I tried this:

```
<textarea name="content"  id="content"></textarea>

for (let i=0; i<3; i++){
   document.getElementById("content").value+= "A\n"";
}
```